# Matrix of dependencies between 2 subpasses, from attachment usage

Tags: vulkan

[image]

Please, help me figure out the possible dependencies between 2 subpasses that use 1 attachment.

The grid represents the way an attachment can be used between 2 subpasses. Cell D.6 means than an attachment is used as input attachment in the first subpass, and then as a depth-test attachment in the second subpass. Since that's a read/read operation, there is no dependency between the subpasses. D.4 means attachment is first used as input attachment, then as color attachment, thus read/write dependency. The blank cells are what's currently missing.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of this exercise is. Many of those combinations don't make sense. The Preserve transitions don't directly need memory dependencies. An attachment can be both color and input in the same subpass, which your matrix doesn't recognize. And there's no point in looking at any transition *into* resolve, since that operation will overwrite the entire image region, so you wouldn't use it for an attachment you'd already modified.

Comment: I'm writing code to generate dependencies between subpasses based on the references to attachments which the subpasses have.

Comment: There is also no such thing as a "depth-test" attachment. Depth attachments are depth attachments, period. A user can choose to use a depth attachment without writes by turning off writing to it, but that doesn't happen at the level of the subpass; it's a part of the graphics pipeline.

Comment: "depth-test" means the depth attachment is used in a read-only way. So, if 2 subpasses use a depth attachment only for test, there is no dependency. You mentioned that many combinations don't make sense -- those are also good to know, because that can be encoded into the handling code. I didn't know, for example, that an attachment can be both color and input, so thanks for that info.